# Loading Icon on Loading Page

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am not sure if "Loading Page Logo" on mobile app is working with current release of salesforce 1. Looks like Brand Color and Loading Page Color is working but I have problem displaying loading image. I tried with png and gif with specified image size 460 x 560 but without luck.

Does anyone get this working?

http://blog.sonomapartners.com/2014/05/salesforce1-mobile-branding-your-mobile-application.html

Comment: Yes, I've gotten this working at my last job, where we had a custom branding color and logo.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example grabbed from Google Chrome in emulation mode:

[image: Custom Salesforce1 Logo]

Here's the settings that I used for branding. The logo I selected is a 256x256 transparent PNG.

[image]

*(What? Were you expecting something other than a fox?)*

Comment: Yes after clearing cache it works on browser, but still have the problem with mobile app(ios app). Wonder if anyone has successfully done with mobile app

Comment: I've tested this before and it works. I'm not sure what problem you're having, but it might just be something simple.

Comment: Are you saying it works on both browser and ios app? How long ago you have tested?

Comment: It was within the last nine months. I could test it on my wife's phone when I get home.

Comment: There is a case it worked was when you add multiple accounts to the app and logged into another account and switch to another org then the loading icon will started showing up